# What design pattern to mimic vertex/fragment shaders in a software renderer?

Tags: c++, templates, opengl, design-patterns, c++11

I have a software renderer that is similar designed to the OpenGL 2.0+ rendering pipeline, however, my software renderer is quite static in its functionality. I would like to design it so I can put in custom vertex- and fragment-"shaders" (written as C++ "functions", not in the OpenGL language), however, I'm not sure how to implement a good, reusable, extensible solution.

Basically I want to choose between a custom "function" that is then called in my renderer to process every vertex (or fragment). So maybe I could work with a function object passed to the renderer, or work out some inheritance-based solution or I'm thinking this could be a case for a template-based solution.

I imagine it like this:

```
for every vertex
  // call the vertex-shading function given by the user, with the standard
  // arguments plus the custom ones given in user code. May produce some custom
  // output that has to be fed into the fragment shader below
end
// do some generic rendering-stuff like clipping etc.
for every triangle
  for every pixel in the triangle        
    // call the fragment-shading function given by the user, with the standard
    // arguments, plus the custom ones from the vertex shader and the ones 
    // given in user code
  end
end
```

I can program C++ quite well, however I don't have much practical experience with templates and the more advanced stuff - I have read a lot and watched a lot of videos though.

There's a few requirements like that one of those "shader-functions" can have multiple (different) input and output variables. There is 2-3 parameters that are not optional and always the same (like the input to a vertex-shader is obviously the triangle, and the output is the transformed position), but one shader could e.g. also require an additional weight-parameter or barycentric coordinates as input. Also, it should be possible to feed one of such custom outputs of the vertex shader into a corresponding fragment shader (like in OpenGL where the output of a variable in the vertex shader is fed into the fragment shader).

At the same time, I would also prefer a simple solution - it shouldn't be too advanced (like I don't want to mimic the GLSL compiler, or have my own DSL). It should just be something like - write VertexShaderA and VertexShaderB and be able to plug them both into my Renderer, along with some parameters depending on the shader.

I would like if the solution uses "modern" C++, as in basically everything that compiles with VS2013 and gcc-4.8.

So to rephrase my main question:

**How can I accomplish this "passing of custom functions to my renderer", with the additional functionality mentioned?**

If possible, I would welcome a bit of example code to help get me started.

Comment: Sounds like you want `std::function`, no?

Comment: @ChristianHackl Well that would be a start, but 1) the function I pass can't access members from the renderer class? and 2) how could I handle the "pass the parameters from the vertex shader to the fragment shader"?

Answer (score 1):

TinyRenderer is a very simple but rather elegant implementation of around 500 lines and it has some wiki with a tutorial. See https://github.com/ssloy/tinyrenderer and the actual shader https://github.com/ssloy/tinyrenderer/blob/master/main.cpp